# Android - TextView pushing up Imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, android-xml

I have some linear layouts containing some texts with images below them. Everything is fine until my text splits into 2 lines because of the lack of space. **My image is being pushed up by the text, and I want to avoid that**, but I can't achieve it.

*Here's my XML code:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imagen_entorno"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/black">
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/imagen_entorno"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:paddingBottom="75dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearRoot"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton1"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton2"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton3"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:layout_below="@id/linear1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/boton4"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tituloSonido4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pajaro mas largo aun"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:lines="2"
                    android:layout_below="@id/boton4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/boton5"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tituloSonido5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pajaro"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/boton6"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tituloSonido6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pajaro"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear3"
                android:layout_below="@id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton7"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:lines="2"
                        android:layout_below="@id/boton4"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton8"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido8"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton9"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido9"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

*Screenshot of the problem:*

[image]

Any tip is appreciated :)

Comment: you can use `android:ellipsize="end"`

Comment: can you share the image that you want to achieve

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I can't hide the text. I need to show it entirely.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh The same just without the image pushed. https://gyazo.com/7ed7c3b2c4dbc0a821ba71363cdba633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the textView can drop to two lines because of lack of space instead of fixing the height set lines to 2 for each textView and apply gravity center. It will intact all text views with respect to height.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="test"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Woah! I had not thought of that idea. That's solve the entire problem. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 2):

Too many views used, Use  [GridView](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html), This link will help you.

Comment: Yes, I should have used it. Maybe I should remake the entire layout.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for make your my image is being pushed up by the text is fix the height for **all** `TextView` by set `layout_height`

```
android:layout_height="30dp"
```

or set the `lines`

```
android:lines="1" // or 2,3 ....
```

If you just want to keep the image where it is when the line splits into 2 or more lines. you need to use `GridView`

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    weight_sum="4"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton2"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
```

avoid using wrap_content in order to get fix size views. You can add a weight_sum property to LinearLayout and assign a value for example 4. Add layout_weight properties to sub views as well.Assign 3 to imaveView and 1 for textview now imageview always will be bigger than textview 3times and textview can not invade imagevies's space. ofc you can assign different values to them to get different size views as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your layout with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imagen_entorno"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/black">
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/imagen_entorno"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:paddingBottom="75dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearRoot"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton1"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton2"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton3"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:layout_below="@id/linear1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/boton4"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tituloSonido4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pajaro mas largo aun"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:lines="2"
                    android:layout_below="@id/boton4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/boton5"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tituloSonido5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pajaro"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/boton6"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tituloSonido6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Pajaro"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear3"
                android:layout_below="@id/linear1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton7"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:lines="2"
                        android:layout_below="@id/boton4"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton8"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido8"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/boton9"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/botones_sonidos"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tituloSonido9"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Pajaro"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        fontPath="fonts/helveticalight.ttf"
                        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fixate the height of that `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tituloSonido3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
...    
/>
```

If you want only one line, you can ellipsize it and set a smaller size.
If you want multiple, you can use an increased height.

Comment: I can't  hide any text and I don't want one line. I need to show the entire text. I just want to keep the image where it is when the line splits into 2 or more lines.